# What is the address of cell $C$12 in R1C1 notation?

Tags: excel, vba

As part of a practice quiz this question was asked and I wrote down R12C3. I was graded incorrect but everywhere I look online it seems I'm correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R12C3 would be right, since you can select C12 and switch to R1C1 in Excel => Options => Formulas => R1C1 notation

So if the reference is "A1" then R12C3 would be right.

If the question was meant to be relative to another cell, the notation would be otherwise
e.g.: Starting from B3 the R1C1 formula would be R[9]C[1] to reach C12

Comment: That was the whole question word for word, no reference to another cell. That's why being marked wrong is throwing me off.

Comment: Starting from B3 wouldn't the R1C1 notation be `R[9]C[1]` for relative and `R12C3` for absolute?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: absolutely right. I edited that in my answer. Thanks for the hint.